# Trying to invoke help (CTRL-H) deletes character on terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

When I press `CTRL-H` in emacs running on my xterm, then this is interpreted as backspace and the character before the point is deleted. I've found various discussions about the "opposite" issue (pressing backspace invokes help), but was unable to modify them to my needs.

How can I access help commands (like the describe functions) from a `emacs -nw` running in an xterm with the keystroke `CTRL-H` ?

*GNU Emacs 24.5.2, XTerm(312), NixOS x86_64, empty .emacs*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode`.

See the Emacs manual, node [DEL Does Not Delete](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html).

> In all of those cases, the immediate remedy is the same: use the
>   command `M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode`.

...

> Another way to fix the problem for every Emacs session is to
>   customize the variable `normal-erase-is-backspace`: the value `t`
>   specifies the mode where `<BS>` or `<BACKSPACE>` is `<DEL>`, and `nil`
>   specifies the other mode.

Comment: Indeed, works. And I think I also begin to understand why. Thank you very much!