# Why does Emacs when started with 'no window' delete a character when I press C-h?

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes

I've recently started to see the following behavior: when I run Emacs via `emacs -nw -Q`, and hit `C-h`, it runs `BACKSPACE`, deleting the characters.

But if I run the same Emacs version in GUI mode, that is, via `emacs -Q`, then `C-h` works as expected. I'm baffled by this.

`(emacs-version)` returns:

```
"GNU Emacs 30.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.16.0)                                                                                                                                                  
 of 2023-10-13"
```

The operating system is [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/jammy-released/), 22.04.3 LTS, running inside VirtualBox, Version 7.0.10 on a ThinkPad T590, operating system is MS Windows 10 Pro (22H2).

Did anybody experience similar problems recently and find a workaround?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think I have the reverse problem, in the sense that in my case, Backspace doesn't invoke help. My problem is that C-h is deleting the characters, instead of its default behavior of  invoking `help-command`, not that Backspace  On top of that, having a discrepancy between the no window mode and GUI mode.  I don't remember having C-h acting differently in previous versions (with regard to no window and GUI mode).

Comment: Did you build Emacs yourself or did you get a pre-built version? Does the problem exist with a released version (probably Emacs 29.1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does BACKSPACE generate C-h?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78911/why-does-backspace-generate-c-h)

Comment: @NickD I didn't build Emacs myself, I use `emacs-snapshot` package in Lubuntu. `dpkg` returns the version as `20231013:107566-bd297132016~ubuntu22.04.1`. I'll check if the same problem exists in the latest released version.

Comment: @Drew it's like I have the opposite problem: when I run it as `emacs -nw -Q`, both the 'Delete' and 'Backspace' keys do what I expect, deleting characters as I expect. My problem is: `C-h` also deletes characters; when I `view-lossage` I see that hitting `C-h` ran: `DEL   ;; backward-delete-char-untabify`. But when I run it as `emacs -Q`, then `C-h` works as I expect, it *does not* delete characters but acts as the 'help` prefix key.

Comment: I've just tried the same experiment with an older Emacs version ("GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64--netbsd, GTK+ Version 3.24.35, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2023-03-09") running on NetBSD 9.3, and it doesn't have that problem. I mean running `emacs -nw -Q` definitely doesn't lead to `C-h` deleting characters, it acts as the usual, expected help prefix key combination. Apparently somehow the current Emacs 'development' version seems to be messed up in this regard. The mystery continues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the settings for the terminal in which you're running emacs. Sometimes the terminal maps C-h to delete a character.

Comment: Indeed! I'm running QTerminal 0.17.0, and inside it GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). When I checked with `bind -P | grep -i "delete"`, I've seen that `backward-delete-char can be found on "\C-h", "\C-?".`  And when I type something in the terminal and hit `C-h`, it indeed deletes characters to the left.

Comment: Apparently this issue comes up regularly, e.g. see the following question from 8 years ago: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17511/trying-to-invoke-help-ctrl-h-deletes-character-on-terminal